# Is it good design to have count column or is it better to use join command everytime?

Tags: mysql, database

Let say there are user, post, and like tables and like table has user_id and post_id foreign keys to represent who liked which post. Is it better to have like_count column in post (and update it by trigger command in like table) or use join command every time I need to query the like count?

I first thought it's better to use join command but, after using it for a while, now I think having like_count might be better option. Sometimes I need to join many tables in real situation and using additional join command for getting only number of like of certain post seems worse idea than having count_post column. Please advise me.

*I searched to find similar discussion but failed so I post this question. If this is duplicated, please let me know.

Comment: How often do you plan to do count queries?  If you plan to do them very infrequently then maybe using a trigger approach would be wasteful.  On the other hand, if you plan to do the count queries often it might be more economical to update the count once with a trigger and then read many times at no extra cost.

Comment: Good point. I expect the application will read more than write so I'd go with creating like_count column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about the difference between the following two queries:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(user_id)
FROM like
GROUP BY post_id;

SELECT post_id, like_count
FROM post;
```

Assuming you have been incrementing `like_count` every time a row is created in the `like` table.

Also note that a join is not necessary to get the count, because you can get it just by doing a GROUP BY against the `like` table alone.

It's a common form of denormalization to calculate an aggregate (like a count) and store it.

Strictly speaking, this is redundant information, which creates the possibilities of data anomalies. There's a risk that your code might fail sometimes to update the `like_count`, and then the count would be inaccurate.

If you are willing to accept this risk, then you can avoid doing the aggregate query every time you want the count.